# Laravel Passport - Grant Type No es soportado

Tags: laravel, passport

```
{
"error": "unsupported_grant_type",
"message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
"hint": "Check the `grant_type` parameter"
```

}

Respuesta al hacer la petición mediante post,el grant_type no es soportado, ¿alguna idea de la solución?

Comment: podrias poner tambien el codigo donde envias el formulario o los datos.

Comment: ¿el formulario del html?

Comment: Bueno ya se soluciono el error, lo que hay qye hacer es enviar los parametros en body no el headers, en la opcion de **form-data**... y ya.( aclaro que estas peticiones las hice desde el **POSTMAN**)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      entrar(usuario:Usuario){

    let datos = {
      'grant_type':'password',
      'client_id' : '1',
      'client_secret' : '5ecVgDAqCV5hgBBREbOhnJMwKC2eGq7ffv4VwPyM',
      'username':usuario.username,
      'password':usuario.password,
      'scope':'*'
    }


    return this.http.post<any>(this.url+"/oauth/token", datos);
  }
```

esto lo hago desde ionic, es el metodo para acceder..